# Optimal way to pull the most recent goal value for each unique goal with this table structure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a table structured similarly to this:

| GoalID | GoalName | GoalType | UsedTimeframe | ChangedTimeframe | GoalUpperBound | GoalLowerBound | GoalValue | EffectiveDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sales | Single Target | Annually | Annually | NULL | NULL | 5,000,000 | 01-01-2021 | 12-31-2021 |
| 2 | Unique Purchasers | Range | Monthly | Monthly | 22,000 | 20,000 | NULL | 9-01-2021 | 9-30-2021 |
| 3 | Sales | Single Target | Monthly | Annually | NULL | NULL | 500,000 | 10-01-2021 | 10-31-2021 |
| 4 | Unique Purchasers | Range | Monthly | Monthly | 24,000 | 21,000 | NULL | 10-01-2021 | 10-31-2021 |
| 5 | New Customers | Single Target | Monthly | Annually | NULL | NULL | 5,000 | 01-01-2021 | 12-31-2021 |
| 6 | Products Sold | Range | Monthly | Monthly | 10,000 | 9,000 | NULL | 10-01-2021 | 10-31-2021 |
| 7 | Products Sold | Range | Monthly | Monthly | 12,000 | 10,000 | NULL | 10-15-2021 | 10-31-2021 |
| 8 | Sales | Single Target | Annually | Annually | NULL | NULL | 4,750,000 | 01-01-2020 | 12-31-2020 |
| 9 | Referrals | Single Target | Monthly | Annually | NULL | NULL | 1,000 | 01-01-2021 | 12-31-2021 |

What is the most optimal way to pull each unique GoalName and their corresponding GoalUpperBound/GoalLowerBound or GoalValue? So in this example, if I wanted to pull all goals that change Monthly, I'd want to see GoalIDs (3, 4, 5, 7, 9) and if I was pulling goals that change Annually, I'd see GoalID (1). I was thinking pulling the MAX(GoalID) for each DISTINCT GoalName and UsedTimeframe and then joining back the GoalID to this table or maybe the MAX(EffectiveDate)?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: Yes. You seem to want to do something informally called "groupwise max", where you wish to obtain the most recent row per `x` group based on some `y` ordering.  Did you always want the GoalID associated with the `MAX(EffectiveDate)` for each `GoalName`?  It's usually best not to depend on the GoalID values unless you know that order satisfies your requirement always.  Get the logic right first, then work on performance as a separate step.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: To address performance, you'll want to provide more detail, like the `CREATE TABLE` statement, including all constraints / indexes, plus some information about the size / range of the data involved.  Your database will often be able to help by showing the `explain plan` for various test cases with sufficient data.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Teasing us with a structure that is _like_ your table and where every column is `NVarChar(MAX)` doesn't help us help you. Providing consumable sample data, expected results and your code does help. So does explaining the data, e.g. how does `UsedTimeframe` affect the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the windowing functions, specifically `ROW_NUMBER()` to number the groups my `GoalID DESC` - then you just want the groups with a `ROW_NUMBER()` = 1. Since you can't use windowing functions in a `WHERE` clause, you have to write it as a subquery.

To test this out, I created a table variable and put your data into it:

```sql
DECLARE @Goals AS TABLE (
    GoalID INT NOT NULL, 
    GoalName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    GoalType VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    UsedTimeframe VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    ChangedTimeframe VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    GoalUpperBound INT NULL,
    GoalLowerBound INT NULL,
    GoalValue INT NULL,
    EffectiveDate DATE NOT NULL,
    EndDate DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Goals(GoalID,GoalName,GoalType,UsedTimeframe,ChangedTimeframe,GoalUpperBound,GoalLowerBound,GoalValue,EffectiveDate,EndDate)
VALUES 
(1,'Sales','Single Target','Annually','Annually',NULL,NULL,5000000,'01-01-2021','12-31-2021'),
(2,'Unique Purchasers','Range','Monthly','Monthly',22000,20000,NULL,'9-01-2021','9-30-2021'),
(3,'Sales','Single Target','Monthly','Annually',NULL,NULL,500000,'10-01-2021','10-31-2021'),
(4,'Unique Purchasers','Range','Monthly','Monthly',24000,21000,NULL,'10-01-2021','10-31-2021'),
(5,'New Customers','Single Target','Monthly','Annually',NULL,NULL,5000,'01-01-2021','12-31-2021'),
(6,'Products Sold','Range','Monthly','Monthly',10000,9000,NULL,'10-01-2021','10-31-2021'),
(7,'Products Sold','Range','Monthly','Monthly',12000,10000,NULL,'10-15-2021','10-31-2021'),
(8,'Sales','Single Target','Annually','Annually',NULL,NULL,4750000,'01-01-2020','12-31-2020'),
(9,'Referrals','Single Target','Monthly','Annually',NULL,NULL,1000,'01-01-2021','12-31-2021');
```

The query is then:

```sql
SELECT GoalID,GoalName,GoalType,UsedTimeframe,ChangedTimeframe,GoalUpperBound,GoalLowerBound,GoalValue,EffectiveDate,EndDate 
FROM 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GoalName ORDER BY GoalID DESC) AS rn
    FROM @Goals 
    WHERE UsedTimeframe = 'Monthly' 
) AS orderedSubQuery 
WHERE rn = 1 
ORDER BY GoalID
```

This returns Goals 3, 4, 5, 7, 9 as you requested.